# Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to ionic://localhost (on cordova-ios)

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, compass-geolocation, cordova-ios

I'm trying to get mobile device's location and orientation (compass heading) with a "location.service" I created. It used to work both on android and ios, now on ios, I get the location, but with an error for device orientation.

> [blocked] Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection
>   to ionic://localhost.
>
> Geolocation PositionError {code: 1, message: "Origin does not have
>   permission to use Geolocation service"

I have tried all of these on *.plist file:
[image]

Im using:

- @angular/cli 7.3.9
- cordova-lib@9.0.1

  - platforms:

    - android 8.1.0
    - ios 5.1.1
  - plugins (shorten):

    - **cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"**
    - cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"

When I `cordova build ios`, run it from Xcode on my iPhone (ios 13.4.1) and check Safari's develop console:
[image]

[image]

location.service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, fromEvent, Observable, of, timer} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Globals } from '../globals';

export interface DefiLocation {
  accuracy: number;
  altitude: number;
  altitudeAccuracy: number;
  heading: number;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  speed: number;
  compass: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationService {
  errorMessage$: string;
  currentLocation$: BehaviorSubject<{
    accuracy?: number,
    altitude: number,
    altitudeAccuracy: number,
    heading: number,
    latitude: number,
    longitude: number,
    speed: number
  }> = new BehaviorSubject({
    accuracy: 0,
    altitude: 0,
    altitudeAccuracy: 0,
    heading: 0,
    latitude: 32.5,
    longitude: 35,
    speed: 0,
  });

  currentCompass$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  currentCompass: number = 0;
  currentPosition: {
    accuracy: 0,
    altitude: 0,
    altitudeAccuracy: 0,
    heading: 0,
    latitude: 32.5,
    longitude: 35,
    speed: 0,
  };
  locationTimer;
  sendLocationError: boolean = true;

  constructor(public globals: Globals) {
    this.isCurrentPosition$.next(true);
    this.trackMe();
  }

  private trackMe() {
    if (this.globals.iphone) {
        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (event) => {
          this.currentCompass$.next(Math.round(event['webkitCompassHeading']));
        });
      // }
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('deviceorientationabsolute', (event) => {
        this.currentCompass$.next(360 - Math.round(event['alpha']));
      }, true);
    }


    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      this.locationTimer = timer(0, 100).subscribe(tick => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          this.currentLocation$.next(position.coords);
          this.isCurrentPosition$.next(true);
          this.sendLocationError = true;
        }, (err) => {
          this.isCurrentPosition$.next(false);
          this.sendError(err.message);
          console.log(err);
          this.errorMessage$ = err.message;
          console.log(this.errorMessage$);
        }, {
          enableHighAccuracy: true
        });
      });

    } else {
      alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
      this.sendError('navigator.geolocation = null ("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")');
    }
  }

  getCurrentLocation$(): Observable<DefiLocation> {
    return combineLatest(this.currentCompass$.asObservable(), this.currentLocation$.asObservable())
      .pipe(
        map(([compass, location]) => {
            return {
              longitude: location.longitude,
              latitude: location.latitude,
              accuracy: location.accuracy,
              altitude: location.altitude,
              altitudeAccuracy: location.altitudeAccuracy,
              heading: location.heading,
              speed: location.speed,
              compass
            };
          }
        ));
  }

  sendError(error) {
    if (this.sendLocationError) {
      this.sendLocationError = false;
      window['cordova'].plugins.firebase.analytics.logEvent('user_location_failed', {param1: error});
      setTimeout(function() { this.sendLocationError = true; }, 5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  I'm using plain Cordova (no Ionic) and I get a similar error trying to "ugrade" to wkwebview "Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to app://localhost".

Comment: I wrote everything I got... @JessePangburn

Comment: Thank you!  My problem was that prior to using WKWebView I didn't need the cordova-plugin-geolocation plugin.  Adding this plugin resolved the issue, although people should be aware that the plugin has a hardcoded 5 meter distance filter which is different than how navigator.geolocation.watchPosition worked without the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error message didn't relate to the device's location (when I fixed the location the error was still there). The orientation was a little more of a problem but I have an answer:

1. **Location -** When I asked for all the right permission in the .plist file I received a proper location. [Here is a nice explanation](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/blocked-access-to-geolocation-was-blocked-over-insecure-connection-to-http-localhost-8080/120364) about the permissions. BTW, i'm using [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/).
2. **Orientation (compass) -** according to the "[Safari 13 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-13-release-notes?preferredLanguage=occ)":

> Added a permission API on iOS for DeviceMotionEvent and
> DeviceOrientationEvent.

a. Permission API - Up-until now, Chrome and Safari only showed a warning about "asking device orientation without user gesture", but on ios 13+ apple took it another step and totally blocked it. [The full w3c discussion](https://github.com/w3c/deviceorientation/issues/57). **Example for the right way to ask premission in the *last* code sample below.**

b. The old/new alternative ([cordova-plugin-device-orientation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation)) -  because this behaviour is really unnatural in an app, I tried an old deprecated plugin that uses native resources, which worked, and luckily, now the plugin is actually undeprecated!

---

### My complete code with fallbacks

1. Trying to ask for permission on location and orientation from the browser on deviceready (with adaptation for android and ios).
2. If not, trying orientation-plugin (native resource).
3. If not, asking permission on user gesture as ios13+ web protocol state.

This run's on deviceready:

```
private trackMe() {

    // compass listener (also ios13+ fallback at "compassPremissioniOS13" funtion)
    if (typeof DeviceOrientationEvent['requestPermission'] !== 'function') {
      const deviceOrientationLestener = (event) => {
        if (this.globals.iphone) {
          this.currentCompass$.next(event['webkitCompassHeading']);
        } else {
          if (event.absolute) {
            this.currentCompass$.next(360 - event.alpha);
          } else {
            window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceOrientationLestener);
            window.addEventListener('deviceorientationabsolute', (eventB) => {
              this.currentCompass$.next(360 - eventB['alpha']);
            }, true);
          }
        }
      };
      window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceOrientationLestener);
    }  else {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
        navigator['compass'].watchHeading((head) => {
          this.currentCompass$.next(head.trueHeading);
        }, (error) => console.log(error), {frequency: 10});
      }, false);
    }

    // GET LOCATION - energy saving and preformance inhancing for mobile, dumm and cyclic for desktop.
    if (this.globals.cordova) {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
            this.currentLocation$.next(position.coords);
            this.isCurrentPosition$.next(true);
            this.sendLocationError = true;
          }, (err) => {
            this.isCurrentPosition$.next(false);
            this.sendError(err.message);
            this.errorMessage$ = err.message;
          }, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
          });
        } else {
          alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
          this.sendError('navigator.geolocation = null ("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")');
        }
      }, false);
    } else {
      if (navigator.geolocation) { // fallback for desktop testing
        this.locationTimer = timer(0, 100).subscribe(tick => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            this.currentLocation$.next(position.coords);
            this.isCurrentPosition$.next(true);
            this.sendLocationError = true;
          }, (err) => {
            this.isCurrentPosition$.next(false);
            this.sendError(err.message);
            this.errorMessage$ = err.message;
          }, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
          });
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
        this.sendError('navigator.geolocation = null ("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")');
      }
    }
  }
```

This runs when user press on navigation button:

```
compassPremissioniOS13$() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        if (typeof DeviceOrientationEvent['requestPermission'] === 'function') {
          DeviceOrientationEvent['requestPermission']()
            .then(permissionState => {
              if (permissionState === 'granted') {
                window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (event) => {
                  this.currentCompass$.next(event['webkitCompassHeading']);
                });
                resolve('User accepted');
              } else {
                reject('User declined');
              }
            })
            .catch(console.error);
        }
      } else {
        alert('deviceorientation is not supported by this browser.');
        this.sendError('deviceorientation = null ("deviceorientation is not supported by this browser.")');
      }
    });
  }
```